# SQLite query Join

Tags: sqlite

I have a query I need to perform in SQLite that is probably fairly simple but I cannot seem to figure out a solution.

I have two tables formed as such:

```
  table_1
value | timestamp
x1    | 0
x2    | 1
x3    | 2
x4    | 3
x5    | 4

  table_2
start | end
0     |  1
2     |  4
```

I want to return a result that looks like:

```
 start  |   end   |       computed_value
 0      |    1    |    avg(x1,x2) * (1 - 0)
 2      |    4    |    avg(x3,x4,x5) * (4 - 2)
```

Where avg(x1,x2) is the actual average values of x1 and x2.  How can I complete this task?

Comment: So your expected results are 0.5 and 6?  You need to use `group by` and `avg` to accomplish this...

Comment: my expected results are avg(x1,x2) * 1 and avg(x3,x4,x5) * 2.  I have not given values for x1,x2,x3...etc.

Comment: Do you want a `varchar` result as that particular expression (not evaluated)?  Or is your `value` column actually numeric and you want the expression evaluated?

Comment: I want the value computed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly and the value column is not a `varchar`, but rather `numeric`, you can accomplish this with a `join`, using the `avg()` aggregate:

```
select t2.start, t2.en, 1.0*avg(t1.val)*(t2.en-t2.start)
from table_2 t2
    inner join table_1 t1 on t1.ts between t2.start and t2.en 
group by t2.start, t2.en
```

You may or may not need `1.0*` with sqlite -- old habits from other databases...